# Is the sequence $3n$ is bounded? Prove or disprove.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is one of exercise questions in our textbook. 
Is the sequence $3n$ is bounded? Prove or disprove. 
It first seems that I should use Archimedean property. 
Let $B\in \mathbb R$, and suppose $3n$ is bounded. Then, $3n \le B$. But, I am stuck here because to use the property, I think that the inequality should be $\ge$.

Could you give some hint to prove this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (I didn't mean you have to remove all curly bracket in your question. Curly bracket can denote a sequence. For example, $\{n^2\}$ is a sequence of square numbers. What I want to say is I do not recommand the notation like $\{a_n\} > 0$ or $\{a_n\} + 1 = \{b_n\}$.)

Comment: @SihyunKim Please *state* the Archimedean property that you know, or is given in your textbook. Remember, when you are posting a question, add literally everything you know about the question, and every definition/theorem that you allow the answerers to use. This will make their job easier, and avoid what has happened in an answer below, where you and the answerer seem to have got mixed up. *If you want a property to be used explicitly, mention it*. Do not take me harshly : I wish that your question is answered satisfactorily, hence this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Archimedean says that $1/n_{0}<3/B$ for some $n_{0}$, so $B<3n_{0}$, so $3n\leq B$ for all $n$ is not valid then.

Comment: Could you add some more explanation in the first part? I don't understand  $\frac 1n_0 < \frac 3B$

Comment: Which Archimedean are you using?

Comment: $B \in R$, then there exist $n \in N$ such that $Bn > 3n$.

Comment: I don't think you are saying the correct version.

Comment: Can I ask you which property you used??

Comment: For every $\epsilon>0$, there is a positive integer $n_{0}$ such that $1/n_{0}<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

We will first introduce some common notation. To express the sequence $(3,6,9,\ldots)$, we typically write $\{3n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is the set of all natural numbers.

Now we will prove that the sequence $\{3n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not bounded. Suppose, for a contradiction, that $\{3n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. By definition, there exists a positive real number $B$ such that $$|3n|\le B \mbox{ for all } n\in\mathbb{N}.$$ However, taking $n=\lceil B/3\rceil+1$, where $\lceil x\rceil$ is the smallest integer $\ge x$, violates the above inequality. This gives us our desired contradiction. Hence the sequence $\{3n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not bounded.

Comment: Could you express more about the last sentence (from 'however ...') ??

Comment: If $n=\lceil B/3\rceil+1$ then $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $|3n|=3n=3\lceil B/3\rceil+3\ge 3B/3+3=B+3$. Do you see that this contradicts $|3n|\le B$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Really, the solution boils down to observing that there is a natural number which is $>B/3$.